# CoreXY printer homes in the wrong direction, but moves correctly when moved manually

Tags: homing, corexy, th3d

So I'm using TH3D firmware on my CoreXY printer and when I move it from the LCD it moves correctly, but when I try to home X or Y it goes in the wrong direction. It's set to home to min in firmware. When I set the endstop logic so its always triggered, it homes in the right direction.

Here are my motion settings:

````
#define MKS_PRINTER

// Build Area Size Settings
#define MKS_X_SIZE 300
#define MKS_Y_SIZE 300
#define MKS_Z_SIZE 300

// Endstop Logic Settings
#define MKS_X_ENDSTOP 0
#define MKS_Y_ENDSTOP 0
#define MKS_Z_ENDSTOP 0

// Homing Settings
#define X_HOME_LOCATION 0
#define Y_HOME_LOCATION 0

// Steps per MM Settings
#define MKS_X_STEPS 80
#define MKS_Y_STEPS 80
#define MKS_Z_STEPS 400
#define MKS_E0_STEPS 95
#define MKS_E1_STEPS 95


// Motor Direction Settings
#define MKS_X_DIRECTION 1
#define MKS_Y_DIRECTION 0
#define MKS_Z_DIRECTION 0
#define MKS_E0_DIRECTION 0
#define MKS_E1_DIRECTION 0

// Stepper Driver Settings
#define MKS_X_DRIVER A4988
#define MKS_Y_DRIVER A4988
#define MKS_Z_DRIVER A4988
#define MKS_E0_DRIVER A4988
#define MKS_E1_DRIVER A4988
```
````

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! For which brand/model printer are you using this firmware? If it is a self built you should use vanilla Marlin.

Comment: There is a setting in marlin to invert the home direction.

Comment: @user77232 That is e.g. `#define X_HOME_DIR -1`, but TH3D firmware has wrapped this up and buried this under a few hundred lines of code. That is why I prefer the Marlin repository. I do understand that for some people with a popular and supported printer the TH3D firmware may be easy and convenient, but for advanced users this extra layer has no added value.